# Warnings of "NAs introduced by coercion" in fread function

Tags: r, data.table, large-data, large-files, fread

I am trying to use `fread()` to read in a table of 2 columns (x, y) and ~3 00 million rows (62 GB) and plot the x and y in a scatter plot. I am using "fread" and it works fine if I only use a small portion of the data, like 30000 rows.

But if I run it on the whole data set, I got:
"Warning message:
In setattr(ans, "row.names", .set_row_names(nr)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/11244921.cri16sc001.SC: line 14: 70765 Killed                  Rscript 10_plotZ0Z1.R"

What could be the reason?

Comment: Well, regardless of the `fread()` error, if you try to plot that without using something like a scatterplot-smooth chart, it's likely going to fail miserably. That's far too many points for even base R graphics (it's too many in general, really). How much system RAM do you have? You will need a substantial buffer above 62GB to plot the entirety of the data even with base R graphics and especially if you try it with ggplot2.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am using cluster and currently having 65 GB memory. How to do scatterplot smooth?

Comment: That is not enough memory. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/scatter.smooth & https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lowess.html (you should really consider sampling)

Comment: Thanks, so I am actually using `readLines(con, n=1)` to read the table line by line and use `points()` to plot it point by point. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

You could sample your big file as already suggested in the comments. Unfortunately, it seems that `fread` doesn't have yet such a feature implemented - see [this opened issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/583) (upvoting the feature could motivate the developers to work on it). But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46799622/5193830), if you are on Linux, then try the `shuf -n` shell command:

```
library(data.table)

# Generate some random data
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(10^6), y = rnorm(10^6))
# write to csv file
fwrite(dt, "test-dt.csv")

# Read a random sample of 10^5 rows
dt2 <- fread(cmd = "shuf -n 100000 test-dt.csv")
dt[, plot(x,y)]
```

Alternatively, you could read blocks of rows from your file with multiple calls to `fread` as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801701/5193830).

Comment: Thank you! I think the NAs error occurs because I have a header line that was also read into the table, but I did not notice it first.